# How to conform to NSCopying and implement copyWithZone in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, swift4

I can't conform NSCopying protocol when I try to use the swift 3 way, 
My code is:

```
public func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
    return type(of:self).init(self)
}
```

But an error appears: 
`Cannot call value of non-function type 'ProductType'`

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the solution, change the function for:

```
public func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
     return Swift.type(of:self).init(self)
 }
```